# Do I need to use float:clear to have content show where I want it to show?

Tags: css, css-float, geometry

I have read several of the posts regarding floats, but I am guessing that my naivete is not catching how I can use the solutions to help me. It could be too that my approach is incorrect. Hopefully, someone here can help out.

I have created three circles using `float:left`. The issue that I am having is that the line that should below the three circles floats to the right of the circles. You will notice as you move the vertical divider on http://jsfiddle.net/u7Za3/, the "About Us" moves. I need the "About Us" to stay below the circles.

I am wondering if I need to use `clear` somewhere, but I am not sure where I would need to put it.

**css**

```
.mission-vision-circles {
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 110px 110px 110px 110px;
    -moz-border-radius: 110px 110px 110px 110px;
      border-radius: 110px 110px 110px 110px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ddd;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ddd;
    margin: 20px 5px 20px 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.brightorange {
    border: 0px solid #E05900;
    background: #e05900;
}

.gray {
    border: 0px solid #796e67;
    background: #796e67;
}

.dark {
    border: 0px solid #333;
    background: #333;
}

.mvv-circles-text {
    color: #fff;
    width: 83%;
    margin: 10% auto 0 auto;
}

.mvv-circles-header {
    color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
.mission-vision-circles {
   width: 183px;
    height: 185px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;}

}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
.mvv-circles-text {
    color: #fff;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin: 10% auto 0 auto;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
.mission-vision-circles {width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
      border-radius: 100px 100px 100px 100px;}

}


@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
.mission-vision-circles {width: 160px;
height: 160px;
-webkit-border-radius: 80px 80px 80px 80px;
    -moz-border-radius: 80px 80px 80px 80px;
    border-radius: 80px 80px 80px 80px;}


}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.mission-vision-circles {width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 90px 90px 90px 90px;
    -moz-border-radius: 90px 90px 90px 90px;
    border-radius: 90px 90px 90px 90px;}

}
```

**html**

```
<div class="mission-vision-circles gray">
<h4 class="mvv-circles-header">VALUES</h4>
<span class="mvv-circles-text">Personal growth</span>
<p class="mvv-circles-text">Leading by example</p>
<p class="mvv-circles-text">Helping Others</p>

</div>
<div class="mission-vision-circles brightorange">
<h4 class="mvv-circles-header">MISSION</h4>
<p class="mvv-circles-text">To share stories and experiences about reframing limiting mindsets in order to help you get out of your own way.</p>

</div>
<div class="mission-vision-circles dark">
<h4 class="mvv-circles-header">VISION</h4>
<p class="mvv-circles-text">To see us all living our lives stretched beyond the limitations imposed by our minds.</p>

</div>

<h2>About Me</h2>
```

Thanks

Pam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are both great solutions, but I would always advocate wrapping floating elements somehow. Take a look at how the wrapping div will fully span the height of it's children, showing the background color.

http://jsfiddle.net/3LCMs/

I like to use something like:

```
/* wrap floats */
.group:before,
.group:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
} 
.group:after {
    clear: both;
}
.group {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
```

Comment: thank you. I had read about using clear, but in my case I was not certain where to place it. When I tried something, I made the matter worse. I have seen slight derivations using a container as suggested. I appreciate you showing how it should be done - best practices - if you will.

Answer (score 2):

If you are floating the divs  and want the `h2` stays below add the clear to the `h2`:

```
h2 {
 clear:both;
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/u7Za3/2/**

Answer (score 1):

If you add a style to make your H2 tag clear the float it should work fine.

```
h2 {
    clear: left;
}
```

You could also specify clear: both.